# Topology on completely regular space is weak topology.

Tags: general-topology

Let $(X,T)$ be completely regular space, $C(X,\Bbb R)=\{f\mid f:X\to\Bbb R \text{ cont}\}$. Then show that the weak topology generated by $C(X,\Bbb R)$ is $(X,T)$.

Clearly weak topo is subset of $T$. For converse??

Comment: Show that the weak topology forms a neighborhood base at each point $x$. To do this, take an open neighborhood $U$ around $x$ and find an $f:X\to\Bbb R$ and an open $V\subset\Bbb R$ such that $x\in f^{-1}(V)\subset U$.

Comment: Yeah but how? Using Separation of a point & the closed set??

Comment: Yes, exactly. Just use the map $f$ whose existence is implied by complete regularity and try to find an appropriate $V$.

Answer (score 4):

To show that $T$ is included in the weak topology generated by $C(X,\mathbb R)$, suppose that $U\in T$. If $U$ is empty, then the conclusion is trivial. If $U$ is not empty, consider any $x\in U$. Since $U^c$ is closed, $x\notin U^c$, and $(X,T)$ is completely regular, there exists some $f\in C(X,[0,1])$ such that $f(x)=0$ and $f\equiv 1$ on $U^c$.

Let $V_x=f^{-1}((-\infty,1))$. Since $f$ is continuous and $(-\infty,1)$ is open in $\mathbb R$, $V_x\in T$ and $V_x$ is open also in the weak topology generated by $C(X,\mathbb R)$ by the very definition of the latter topology. It is clear also that $x\in V_x$ and $V_x\subseteq U$. It follows that $U=\bigcup_{x\in U}V_x$, so that $U$—being a union of open sets—is open in the weak topology generated by $C(X,\mathbb R)$.